# Python merging dictionary of dictionaries into one dictionary by summing the value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge, addition

I want to merge all the dictionaries in a dictionary, while ignoring the main dictionary keys, and summing the value of the other dictionaries by value.

Input:

```
{'first':{'a': 5}, 'second':{'a': 10}, 'third':{'b': 5, 'c': 1}}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 15, 'b': 5, 'c': 1}
```

I did:

```
def merge_dicts(large_dictionary):
    result = {}
    for name, dictionary in large_dictionary.items():
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if key not in result:
                result[key] = value
            else:
                result[key] += value
    return result
```

Which works, but I don't think it's such a good way (or less "pythonic").

By the way, I don't like the title I wrote. If anybody thinks of a better wording please edit.

Comment: The only bad thing you do is going over `large_dictionary.items()` instead of `large_dictionary.values()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sum counters, which are a dict subclass:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sum(map(Counter, d.values()), Counter())
Counter({'a': 15, 'b': 5, 'c': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
from collections import defaultdict
values = defaultdict(int)
def combine(d, values):
    for k, v in d.items():
        values[k] += v

for v in a.values():
    combine(v, values)

print(dict(values))
```

Comment: I hadn't put list in defaultdict, i had put defaultdict(lambda : 0), defaultdict(int) and  defaultdict(lambda : 0) result to same. But int will be more pythonic, i also thought.

Comment: @wim Oh. Hmm. I thought it would always return the same list. But it doesn't. Gotta think this through when I have more time. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @wim Yeah ok I'm an idiot... wouldn't have expected `def f(): return []` to always return the same one. Something about `defaultdict(lambda: [])` somehow threw me off. I guess because it looks too similar to parameter default notation.

Answer (score 0):

Almost similar, but it's just short and I like it a little better.

```
def merge_dicts(large_dictionary):
    result = {}
    for d in large_dictionary.values():
        for key, value in d.items():
            result[key] = result.get(key, 0) + value
    return result
```